# How to iterate through a list to produce variables from deserialized JSON C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

Here is my JSON. I am trying to get the 3 station codes into 3 individual variables from this JSON i have deserialized.

```
"stations": [
{
  "station_code": "HWV",
  "atcocode": null,
  "tiploc_code": "HTRWTM5",
  "name": "Heathrow Airport   Terminal 5",
  "mode": "train",
  "longitude": -0.490589,
  "latitude": 51.470051,
  "distance": 369
},
{
  "station_code": "HXX",
  "atcocode": null,
  "tiploc_code": "HTRWAPT",
  "name": "Heathrow Airport   Central Terminal Area (T123)",
  "mode": "train",
  "longitude": -0.454333,
  "latitude": 51.471404,
  "distance": 2309
},
{
  "station_code": "HAF",
  "atcocode": null,
  "tiploc_code": "HTRWTM4",
  "name": "Heathrow Airport   Terminal 4",
  "mode": "train",
  "longitude": -0.445463,
  "latitude": 51.458266,
  "distance": 3336
}
```

And here is my C# where I have firstly made a class for the station code, then deserialized the JSON and have attempted to make a list of station codes to then iterate thorugh them to produce 3 seperate station code variables.

```
public class Station
{
    public string station_code { get; set; }
}

JObject json = JObject.Parse(localJson);

            IList<JToken> results = json["stations"].Children().ToList();

            IList<Station> stationResults = new List<Station>();
            foreach (JToken result in results)
            {
                Station stationResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Station>(result.ToString());
                stationResults.Add(stationResult);
                var station1 = stationResults[0];
                var station2 = stationResults[0];
                var station3 = stationResults[0];
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Im trying to produce 3 different variables for each station_code from the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Change your `foreach` to:

```
foreach (JToken result in results)
{
    // This gives you the current station object from the JToken
    Station stationResult = result.ToObject<Station>();

    // Add to your Station list  
    stationResults.Add(stationResult);
}
```

This will give you the 3 `Station` in your `stationResults` List.  You can access each station in your list using the list index (eg. `stationResults[0]`), or iterate through your list.

I don't see why you would want to assign each item in your list to a single variable.  But if you really want to you can do something like this:

```
Station station1 = stationResults[0];
Station station2 = stationResults[1];
Station station3 = stationResults[2];
```

Comment: From the 3 serpate train stations I am going to get the station code to put into another api link to then show timetables for each train station

Comment: You can access the station_code using `stationResults[0].station_code` and so on.  There is no need to assign the Stations in your results list to individual variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize `localJson` directly into `IList<Station>` because it's an array type.  There's no need to deserialize each one in a foreach loop.

```
var stations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Station>>(localJson);
var station1 = stations[0].station_code;
var station2 = stations[1].station_code;
var station3 = stations[2].station_code;
```